# React почему не работает условный рендеринг?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть функциональный  компонент, хочу в зависимости от условия вывести или App или Win компонент.  но почему то не работает ,что делаю не так?

```
import App from './App';
import Win from './Win';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Main(){
   const [count, setCount] = useState(true);
 
   let button;

   if (count) {
      button = <Win />;
    } else {
      button = <App />;
    } 
return (
   {button}
)

}
export default Main;
```

Comment: А зачем тут фигурные скобки в `return`?

Comment: А как написать в  return - e это добро? return ( { count ? <Win /> : <App />; } ) и со скобками и без не хочет выполнять.Любовь к {} видимо из jsx в котором обертывать то иногда приходится значения.

Comment: `return ( count ? <Win /> : <App /> );` Может вам JS подучить, что бы понимать что означают фигурные скобки и когда они нужны?

Comment: Тебя чо жена не удовлетворила? Ты что с наездами базаришь братишка? не хочешь не отвечай и сиди пыхти от своей умности.Я сюда не экзамен пришел сдавать а вопрос задал. Где в js используется {} это одна история но они используются и в jsx и когда у тебя в return возвращается jsx то иногда эти скобки там есть. Для примера https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html погляди примерчики и там полно в return бывает {}. И раз такой умный то ответь как вернуть в return ( { count ? <Win /> : <App />; } ) подобное? хоть со скобками хоть без как бы не работает.

Comment: Как правильно — написано в начале предыдущего комментария. Фигурные скобки используются **внутри** JSX как индикатор что это опять нормальный JS, а не синтаксический сахар. Потому что JSX это JS + «сахар» и неплохо бы знать на чём ты пишешь, просто что бы быть нормальным разработчиком, а не очередным «верстальщиком на реакте»…

Comment: Кстати, ещё более короткий вариант: `let Button = count ? Win : App; return <Button/>;`

Comment: Нет короче не короче это не то. Почему я не могу подобную штуку написать в самом return? хотя другие вставки в jsx того или иного js кода вполне прокатывают.

Comment: Я сдаюсь. Неплохо бы знать синтаксис языка на котором вы пишите, но раз не хотите, то мне больше заплатят…

Comment: Я тебя расстрою, однажды ты умрешь и все твои знания будут той иллюзией, которую ты создал о самом себе и в которую ты верил. И по итогу больше получит то кто помогал  а не выделывался.А уж если и выделывается то уж тогда и отвечай за базар. return может возвращать jsx тот самый сахарок который заменяется под копотном на вызов функций ,и вот если ты попробуешь в return вписать другой код и с {} то он замечательно отработает а count ? Win : App; return хоть оберни хоть нет не срабатывает.но при этом через переменную let button он срабатывает,и дело здесь не в синтаксисе а какой то мутки react

Comment: Запихай мне эту конструкцию count ? Win : App; в return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо просто без фигурных скобок:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Win = () => <button> Win </button>;
const App = () => <button> App </button>;

function Main() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(true);

  const button = count ? <Win /> : <App />;

  return button;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо друг .А почему интересно не работает вот так return (
   { count ? <Win /> : <App />; }
   )

Comment: Если честно, не знаю, почему в фигурных скобках не работает, не писал так. Но если напишите без фигурных и круглых скобок, то будет работать

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов это просто невалидный код. И откуда такая странная любовь к фигурным скобкам?